# Check JSON and push

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I've got an object oInfoModal as below.

```
var oInfoModal = {"modals" : [
{"myID" : 4,"myVals" : [{2,5,7}]},
{"myID" : 9,"myVals" : [{13,8,6}]},
{"myID" : 6,"myVals" : [{1}]}
] };
```

What I'm trying to do is process some incoming data and check if a value exists for that incoming data. 
i.e. if myID of 6 exists add myIdx to myVals. 
But if myID of 6 doesn't exist, build the sub-object and push it into oInfoModal.

```
function processFunction(idx){
  var myIdx = 3;  // 
  var myID = 6;

  var existsMyID = $.map(oInfoModal.modals, function(elem, index) {
    if (elem.myID == myID){ 
      // myID is found in oInfoModal
      return true;
    } else{
      // myID not found in oInfoModal
      return false;
    }
  });

  if (existsMyID){ 
     // myID is found in oInfoModal. push myIdx to myVals for myID=6 in oInfoModal          
     // How?
  } else { 
     //  myID not found in oInfoModal.  Create and push full object to oInfoModal
     var myObj = {"myID" : myID,"myVals" : myIdx};        
     oInfoModal.modals.push( myObj ); // not working
  } 
}
```

I've had a pot of coffee, so that's not it. What am I missing?

Comment: `[{2,5,7}]` is invalid structure

Comment: valid is "myVals": [2,5,7]

Comment: Also `$.map()` returns an array...which will always be truthy

Comment: Ah! Thank you all. Working to correct these mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your values in `myVals` are incorrect. You need to use `array#find` to check if a value exist in your array. If it exist, you can push the new value otherwise add a new object having the id and value.

```js
var oInfoModal = {"modals" : [{"myID" : 4,"myVals" : [2,5,7]},{"myID" : 9,"myVals" : [13,8,6]},{"myID" : 6,"myVals" : [1]}]};

function processFunction(idx){
  var myIdx = 3;  // 
  var myID = 20;
  var existsMyID = oInfoModal.modals.find(function(o){
    return o.myID === myID;
  });

  if(existsMyID)
    existsMyID.myVals.push(myIdx);
  else {
    var myObj = {"myID" : myID, "myVals" : [myIdx]};       
    oInfoModal.modals.push(myObj);
  }
}
processFunction(null);

console.log(oInfoModal);
```

Comment: Much appreciated Hassan, Roy, and charlietfl !